# jquery, unselect checkbox

Tags: jquery

now i get value if i selected checkbox(id which was selected),
but how get value when i unselected (id which was unselected)?

For example I push on 1, and i get value 1. When I unselect 1, i get value 1.
I hope you understand my problem.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(event){
        $("#result").html("&id=" + this.value);
    });
});
</script>
</head>                                                                 
<body>                                                                
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_pref" value = "1"/>1
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_pref" value = "2"/>2
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_pref" value = "3"/>3 
<div id="result">result ...</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply create an array with all the checked values.

Then i can use `join` to create string out of it for later use.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $inputs = $("input[type=checkbox]");
    $inputs.change(function(event){
        var list = [];
        $inputs.filter(':checked').each(function() {
            list.push($(this).val());
        });
        $("#result").html("&id=" + list.join(",")); // Produces: &id = 1,2,3 (If they were all checked)
    });
});
```

​

Comment: .. I just tried this and it didn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/8nhYq/. Are you sure this works?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the syntax errors, try: http://jsfiddle.net/8nhYq/1/, post updated with valid JS

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you use this.attr('checked') you should get back a boolean.

or you could do

this.is(':checked')